# Как правильно передать POST запрос requests

Tags: python, post, requests

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно передать POST запрос из такого набора данных?
`curl --request POST \ --url https://goo.su/api/links/create \ --header 'content-type: application/json' \ --header 'x-goo-api-token: XXXXXX' \ --data '{ "url":"https://www.api.com", "alias":"cool", "is_public": true, "group_id":2 }'`

Такое не сработало 404 Not Found. Unknown API Method.

```
import requests
b = 'https://goo.su/api/links/create/application/json/TOKEN-XXXX'
r = requests.post(b, data={"url":"https://*", "alias":"cool", "is_public": "true", "group_id":2})
```

Вот такое ввожу

```
try:
    import http.client as http_client
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import httplib as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

# You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True


# Test
import requests
API_KEY = 'XXX'
url = 'https://goo.su/api/links/create'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','x-goo-api-token': API_KEY}
data = {"url":"https://vk.com/", "alias":"cool", "is_public": "true", "group_id":2}
rs = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
#rs = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
print(rs)
print(rs.url)
print(rs.history)
print(rs.cookies)
print(rs.text)
```

Вот такое получаю

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): goo.su:443
send: b'POST /api/links/create HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: goo.su\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\ncontent-type: application/json\r\nx-goo-api-token: XXX\r\nContent-Length: 64\r\n\r\n'
send: b'POST /api/links/create HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: goo.su\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\ncontent-type: application/json\r\nx-goo-api-token: XXX\r\nContent-Length: 64\r\n\r\n'
send: b'url=https%3A%2F%2Fvk.com%2F&alias=cool&is_public=true&group_id=2'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
header: Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2022 10:53:31 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.15
header: Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
header: pragma: no-cache
header: expires: -1
header: X-RateLimit-Limit: 85
header: X-RateLimit-Remaining: 84
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
header: CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
header: Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
header: Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=I6maZNbb%2FOchM%2FkjyEuxex%2FjEi1rL8jg2YqEPDVTpLCyl16ady0dNq1YuFUXmfIetRNtJvairagP4IlWhDUnhpzOtv%2F31z9Y8hx4sNJkiwS19IokHZw%2FAlw%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
header: NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
header: Server: cloudflare
header: CF-RAY: 6ebc774e1f7d162e-DME
header: alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://goo.su:443 "POST /api/links/create HTTP/1.1" 400 None
<Response [400]>
https://goo.su/api/links/create
[]
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
{"message":"Validation error","errors":["The url field is required."]}
```

Comment: Обратил внимание, что у вас явно в теле запроса не json: `url=https%3A%2F%2Fvk.com%2F&alias=cool&is_public=true&group_id=2` это похоже на form-data. Попробуйте `rs = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)` как было в ответе, но уберите из `headers` `content-type`, т.к. `json=` его сам добавит

Comment: Ну и ошибка `{"message":"Validation error","errors":["The url field is required."]}` уже хорошо - понятно, что сервер не смог найти такое-то поле, а это скорее всего из-за проблемы разбора тела запроса, которое оказалось не json

Comment: @gil9red, `{"message":"Validation error","errors":["The url field is required."]}`, а как можно эту ошибку исправить? Удалил из `headers` `'content-type': 'application/json',` остальное не понял как исправить..

Comment: @gil9red, не подскажете может ли быть дело в `You need to use in HTTP requests only HTTPS protocol and UTF-8 encoding. All requests require a header X-Goo-Api-Token.`?  Я просто не разберусь в документации API этой https://goo.su/api-doc#general-information

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо понял. Дело помимо `'content-type': 'application/json'` было еще в `"alias":"cool", "is_public": "true", "group_id":2` удалил их и все ок стало.

Comment: Вы молодец, что разобрались :) Лучше оформите свой ответ или пусть в принятом ответе будет доработка

Comment: Ок, исправил принятый ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
    
url = 'https://goo.su/api/links/create'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','x-goo-api-token': 'XXXXXX'}
data = {"url":"https://betlay.ru", "alias":"cool", "is_public": "true", "group_id":2}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Вместо `'XXXXXX'` вставте ваш токен.

Comment: Спасибо, но возникла ошибка: <Response [400]>. 400 Неправильный Запрос. Запрос содержит недопустимые параметры. Может это как-то поможет?  HTTP-запросах необходимо использовать только протокол HTTPS и кодировку UTF-8. Для всех запросов требуется заголовок X-Goo-Api-Token. Вот инструкция для API https://goo.su/api-doc

Comment: @ChikChirik, можно добавить логирование запроса, чтобы увидеть что отправляется: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e32cfb390c1d0f5a3c5086c7322c2eafbce9c8dd/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L10

Comment: логгирование не мой конек.

Comment: @gil9red попробовал сделать логирование, дополнил вопрос тем, что получилось. А что с этим дальше делать не понимаю..